# Why can't I delete standard-rwo GCP Storage Class?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have 2 similar GKE Clusters, first running version 1.23.12-gke.100 and other running 1.24.5-gke.600.

Since `standard-rwo` storage class is immutable, to update reclaimPolicy I do the below:

In 1.23 cluster, I can delete standard-rwo class, modify reclaimPolicy and create the storageClass again.

In 1.24 cluster, I cannot delete standard-rwo as it gets recreated immediately. Any suggestions on how to change reclaimPolicy?

Comment: Will look into why things changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a new storage class rather than deleting and (re)creating the existing one.

Less ideal options:
If you do not use dynamic provisioning, you can set the `persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy` on the PV resource itself.

If you are using dynamic provisioning, you can patch the created PV and update the `persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy` as well.

Comment: pff thanks, @gari-singh, I was wondering if there's a better way to do this than creating another storage class. Guess not!

Comment: Added a couple of less than ideal options above as well.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, these sound good. I'll mark this as the correct answer since this covers all possible workaround that we can do. Cheers!